# How to Find the Object is a Value Type OR Reference Types in C#

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

I'm having a Method, it has one parameter of type `object`.

In that I have to find the `object` is `Value Type` or `Reference Type`

```
Public void MyMethod(object param)
{
    if(param is Value Type)
    {
        // Do Some Operation related to Value Type
    } 
    else if(param is Reference Type)
    {
        // Do Some Operation related to Reference Type
    } 
}
```

List of Value Types

- string
- int
- float
- bool, etc.,

List of Reference Types

- List
- Array
- Stack
- Dictionary, etc.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use properties [`IsValueType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IsClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isclass(v=vs.110).aspx) on `Type`:

```
if(param.GetType().IsValueType)
{
    // param is value type
} 
else if(param.GetType().IsClass)
{
    // param is reference type
}
```